# CSS media print background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, watermark, printing-web-page

I want to print a watermark/background image on the print document. The watermark/background image would not be visible on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming a bit late, but you might getting away with absolutely positioning your image, bring down the z-index to -1 and then give it a class specific to print media like .printOnly. With that you can style your @media all

```
.printOnly{
    display:none;
}
```

…then in your @media print just leave that styling open

```
.printOnly{

}
```

As for printing with different browsers I'm getting images out from FF, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible:

["most browsers are configured not to print backgrounds"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) (the reason is, to save toner-ink)

Comment: what about having any div background image

Comment: No CSS-backgrounds will be printed. You have to include the image using the `<img>`-tag, in order to print it—and not even this is reliable, as the user may choose, not to print images at all.

Comment: background:white is the only value browsers respect.

Comment: @feeela. Which browsers provide an option to not print images? I haven't seen this option in any browser.

Comment: @Gerben Ok, maybe described in a wrong way. Opera let me hide any images—I would use that and then print the page.